# Iterate through 2d list and append to multiple other lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a 2-D list:

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[11,12,13,14,15]]
```

I want to store 0 to N-1 of each list in the 2-D list in a separate list and 1 to N in another one. So I create two new lists to be appended where they have the same length as the 2-D lst:

```
alpha, beta = [[]]*len(lst), [[]]*len(lst)
```

Then I run this code:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[i])-1):
        alpha[i].append(lst[i][j])
        beta[i].append(lst[i][j+1])
```

But the for-loops seem to be iterating through all lists every time.

I want to get the result

```
alpha = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[11,12,13,14]]
beta = [[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[12,13,14,15]]
```

Instead, I am getting

```
alpha = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,14],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,14]]
beta = [[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15]]
```

There is definitely something wrong with my code and I'm not able to figure it out, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think list comprehensions might make your code more succinct:

```
alpha = [i[:-1] for i in lst]
beta = [i[1:] for i in lst]

>>> alpha
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
>>> beta
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo, bar= [], []

for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[i])-1):
        foo.append(lst[i][j])
        bar.append(lst[i][j+1])
    alpha[i] = foo
    beta[i] = bar
    foo, bar = [], []
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.